# Connecting Android app to ASP.NET web service: java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found

Tags: c#, android, asp.net

I am learning how to connect an Android app to ASP.NET web service from an online tutorial. When learning, I replaced their web service with one I had written on my own and ran it on a PC from Visual Studio. Then, I called the method 'Add' in the web service from the Android app but I am getting this error:

> java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found

I believe there is something wrong with the SOAP_ADDRESS field below.

```
public final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/Add";

public  final String OPERATION_NAME = "Add";

public  final String WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";

public  final String SOAP_ADDRESS = "12.145.142.45:50428/WebService.asmx";
```

This is the code of my web service.

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]

[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
// [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
public WebService()
{

    //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
    //InitializeComponent(); 
}

[WebMethod]
public int Add(int a, int b)
{
    return a+b;
}

}
```

I think the error is showing up because I cannot specify IP addresses like that directly in Java code. So, my question is what is the correct SOAP_ADDRESS value for connecting the Android app to my ASP.NET web service?

Comment: `SOAP_ADDRESS` must contains the protocol (http/s)

Comment: Using http also gave me the same result. The tutorial hadn't specified http as well but it worked.